# Create a trigger to get current IP address

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community, before-trigger

I want to create a trigger when user (or customer) make changes to record, then I want record their current IP. Does anybody know how that works?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used the below code to get the IP address of the logged/current user. Hope this helps. Thanks

```
    Map<String, String> headersMap = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders();  

    // True-Client-IP has the value when the request is coming via the caching integration.
    String ipAddress = headersMap.get('True-Client-IP');

    if (String.isEmpty(ipAddress)) {
        // X-Salesforce-SIP has the value when no caching integration or via secure URL.
        // get IP address when no caching (sandbox, dev, secure urls)
        ipAddress = headersMap.get('X-Salesforce-SIP');
    } 

    if (String.isEmpty(ipAddress)) {
        // get IP address from standard header if proxy in use
        ipAddress = headersMap.get('X-Forwarded-For');
    } 

    return ipAddress;
```

Comment: Please check this as answer if it resolve the issue. It'll be helpful for others also in future. Good Luck and Thanks

Comment: Hey, the problem is we want to get the source IP field from login history object. We do not know how to get it. We can get the IP but the system randomly chooses a one. Do you have any idea about it?